# Update my.cnf without restarting MySQL

Tags: mysql, configuration

I want to update my *my.cnf* without restarting mysql, is it possible?

In fact I just want to set `lower_case_table_names = 1`, but I do not have the permission to restart MySQL.

Comment: Do you understand what will happen when you change that setting?  You may have a disaster worse than a mere restart.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check MySQL manual if a variable is dynamic: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Unfortunately `lower_case_table_names` is not. So you have to restart MySQL to make this variable picked up.

Comment: Yes I know this variable is read only, I really want to do this without restarting mysql